# Insert and populate Global Array LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to write an LLVM Pass that locates a global array, copies it and inserts a new modified global array. But I can't even insert elements into my new array. I tried many different things such as populating a Value * array, IRBuilder, pushing onto a vector, reading terminal output from clang emit-llvm etc. It appears that Getelementptr load and store should be the best way of doing this but I kept getting errors and the LLVM Documentation does not explain this very well. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"
#include "llvm/IR/InstIterator.h"
#include "llvm/IR/GlobalVariable.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Type.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
using namespace llvm;

namespace {

    struct CopyMod : public FunctionPass
    {
        static char ID;
        const ConstantDataArray *data;
        const GlobalVariable *GR;
        ConstantDataArray *Add;
        GlobalVariable *G;
        Module * Mod;

        CopyMod() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

        bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override
        {
          for (inst_iterator idx = inst_begin(F), E = inst_end(F); idx != E; idx++)
          {
             if(auto *GI = dyn_cast<GetElementPtrInst>(&*idx))
             {
                 for(const Value *Op : GI->operands())
                 {
                     if(GR = dyn_cast<GlobalVariable>(Op))
                     {
                         if(data = dyn_cast<ConstantDataArray>(GR->getInitializer()))
                         {
                             errs() << "Number of Elements we got: " << data->getNumElements() << "\n";

                             for(int k = 0, ed = data->getNumElements(); k < ed; ++k)
                                errs() << data->getElementAsInteger(k) << "\n";

                                Mod = F.getParent();
                                auto dude = Mod->getOrInsertGlobal("new_table", ArrayType::get(Type::getInt32Ty(F.getContext()), 
                                                                                                data->getNumElements()));
                                G = Mod->getNamedGlobal("new_table");
                                G->setLinkage(GlobalValue::LinkageTypes::CommonLinkage);

                                auto arrayType = 
                                    llvm::ArrayType::get(llvm::IntegerType::get(idx->getContext(), 32), data->getNumElements());

                                auto arrayPtr = new llvm::AllocaInst(arrayType, "", idx->getContext());

                                for(auto id = 0; id < data->getNumElements(); ++id)
                                {

                                      auto myElt = llvm::ConstantInt::get(idx->getContext(), llvm::APInt(64, 0, true));
                                      auto myIndex = llvm::ConstantInt::get(idx->getContext(), llvm::APInt(32, id, true));

                                      auto ptr = llvm::GetElementPtrInst::Create(arrayPtr->getType(), arrayPtr, { myElt, myIndex }, "", idx->getParent());
                                      auto store = new llvm::StoreInst(myIndex, ptr, false, idx->getParent());
                                }
                                G->setInitializer((Constant *)arrayPtr);
                         }
                     }

                 }
             }
          }
            return false;
        }
    };
} //End of namespace

char CopyMod::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<CopyMod> X("cpymd", "CopyMod", false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GetElementPtrInst` doesn't perform memory operations. It only computes memory addresses. You've already constructed the new array `dude`, so to populate it with `data`'s elements, we use the loop as you have done except on each iteration, *we compute the address of the current element with the `GEP` instruction*, *create a load operation from that address, and store the value of that load op in the corresponding computed address of the `dude` array* (what a cool name! maybe that's why it always has trouble getting pass code reviews :):) ).

I recommend you use a builder instance, as it's a lot easier. I've modified part your code

```
struct CopyMod : public FunctionPass
{
    static char ID;
    const ConstantDataArray *data;
    const GlobalVariable *GR;
    ConstantDataArray *Add;
    GlobalVariable *G;
    Module * Mod;

    CopyMod() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override
    {
    IRBuilder<> builder(F.getContext());
      for (inst_iterator idx = inst_begin(F), E = inst_end(F); idx != E; idx++)
      {
         if(auto *GI = dyn_cast<GetElementPtrInst>(&*idx))
         {
             for(const Value *Op : GI->operands())
             {
                 if(GR = dyn_cast<GlobalVariable>(Op))
                 {
                     if(data = dyn_cast<ConstantDataArray>(GR->getInitializer()))
                     {
                         errs() << "Number of Elements we got: " << data->getNumElements() << "\n";

                         for(int k = 0, ed = data->getNumElements(); k < ed; ++k)
                            errs() << data->getElementAsInteger(k) << "\n";

                            Mod = F.getParent();
                            auto dude = Mod->getOrInsertGlobal("new_table", data->getType()), 
                                                                                          data->getNumElements()));
                            G = Mod->getNamedGlobal("new_table");
                            G->setLinkage(GlobalValue::LinkageTypes::CommonLinkage);

                            for(auto id = 0; id < data->getNumElements(); ++id)
                            {
                              auto srcAddress = builder.CreateGEP(data, std::vector<Value*>{ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(context), 0), id});
                              auto loadedElem = builder.CreateLoad(srcAddress);
                              auto destAddress = builder.CreateGEP(G, std::vector<Value*>{ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(context), 0), id});
                              builder.CreateStore(loadedElem, destAddress);
                            }

                     }
                 }

             }
         }
      }
        return false;
    }
};
```